# Import huge datasets to Power BI from SSAS cube

Tags: powerbi, ssas, olap-cube

We have stored data in several multidimensional cubes upon which I want to build Power BI reports.

A live connection is not supported so I have to import data from the cube in Analysis Services.

It takes like 12 hours to load around 2 million rows and then I get an error- "**The XML for Analysis request timed out before it was completed**"

I am not sure why is the import unsuccessful and taking so much time. I have also increased the external timeout in SSAS.

It would be of great help if you could suggest a way out.

Many thanks!

Comment: Does your mdx query run ok in SSMS? You should investigate why it takes 12 hours. Do you create one very huge query or multiple small?

Comment: I would recommend building it from the underlying database not from the cube. Live Connection is supported for MD cubes